# What happends if you use strdup on an already allocated memory

Tags: c, multithreading, strdup

I'm having some issue with my stack implementation, my push function manipulate the value i send into the function and changes it. I have tried diffrent ways of constructing this but they either don't work or give me corrupted output.

The base idea is the one below here, **note:** my pop function only walks down one position and doesn't free the memory at the specific position. I can not use strcpy since im working with threads.

Does strdup change the value that it copies, i cant find any information saying that is the case, my understanding is that you are suppose to be able to use the value after it has ben duped.

And how is the **correct** way to use strdup on a already allocated memory space, i assume that i can't just free it and then use it again.

```
void stack_push(Stack *s, char *value)
{
   if (s->size == s->capacity) {
       realloc_stack(s);
   }

   if(s->data[s->size] == NULL){
       // The current position does not contain any data.
       s->data[s->size] = strdup(value);

   }
   else{
       free(s->data[s->size]);
       s->data[s->size] = strndup(value, strlen(value) + 1);
   }

   s->size += 1;

}
```

**Edit** s->data = char **data

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you for the answer. Do you know anything about what it does with the value it dupes?

Comment: You say you are working in a multithreaded environment; since you change state non-atomically in this function, it must be protected by a mutex or such, independent of any library functions you may or may not call (and most of them *are* reentrant). *Do* you protect it?

Comment: It just duplicates it. That's it, nothing more. Why would it do anything else? If you want to use or free the source again later, keep your own pointer to it; `strdup()` won't reuse the same address, as that wouldn't be _duplication_...

Comment: 1) No reason for `strndup(value, strlen(value) + 1);`, `strdup(value);` is fine.  2) I suspect your problem is in unposted `realloc_stack();`

Comment: "Does strdup change the value that it copies" --> No.  Best to post a [mcve].

Comment: Note: The `s->data[s->size] == NULL` is not needed.   Entire `if ...else ...` can be replaced with `free(s->data[s->size]); s->data[s->size] = strdup(value);`.  `free(NULL)` is OK.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Ok, do you mind explaining more what you mean. I do need some sort indexing of my strings

Comment: @forsb Errr... I was wrong. Bummer ;-). Sorry for the confusion. Deleted.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica No worries! It was poorly explained by me :)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the advice, wouldn't free(NULL) generate valgrind errors? It's not likely that the issue lays with the realloc stack function since the porblem occures before size matches capacity

Comment: @forsb The C spec has with `free()`, "If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strdup` is basically this (no error checking for brevity):

```
char *strdup(const char *stringtoduplicate)
{
  char *newstring = malloc(strlen(stringtoduplicate) + 1);
  strcpy(newstring, stringtoduplicate);
  return newstring;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
char Foo[] = "Bar";
char *newBar = strdup(Foo);
Foo[0] = 'F';
printf("%s %s\n", Foo, newBar);   // prints: Far Bar
...
free(newBar);     // once you're done with newBar, free it
```

Now you should be able to answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, s->data corresponds to char **. Will change it in the question

Comment: The OP's code looks ok to me, provided the function is mutex-protected and realloc_stack() does what it's supposed to. Why do you think the OP's program does not work?

Comment: @forsb `strdup`, `strcpy`and `malloc` don't change the source string (why should they?). I suspect you have multithreading problems (poor or non existant synchronisation between threads)

Answer (score 1):

`strdup` does not in any way modify its argument. If you look at the prototype for `strdup` you will see that its parameter is declared `const`, which means that it is not modified.

`strdup` can be implemented as:

```
char* strdup(const char* s) {
    char* n = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (n) strcpy(n, s);
    return n;
}
```

There is no magic.

You can use `strcpy` with threads, by the way. But `strdup` works fine.